# Installation problems on Dell XPS 15z

Tags: system-installation, 11.10, dell, xps, unetbootin

I have a Dell XPS 15z onto which I'm trying to install 11.10. I downloaded the 64 bit ISO image and used UNetbootin to create a bootable USB drive. I plug it in and it boots to the UNetbootin menu.

My menu however, has the following options:

```
Default
Help
Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
Check disc for defects
Test memory
Boot from first hard disk
Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
Check disc for defects
```

*Yes, the last three are repeated.*

It might also be important to note that this menu is displayed in a CLI at what looks like 80x30 characters.

When I select any of the options (even "Boot from first hard disk"), the menu stays the same, but the screen resolution changes so that now the menu (which previously took up the full screen) is not just in the top 1/16th of the screen. After that... nothing. The menu just sits there.

The fan on the computer fires up, so it sounds like it's working hard, but nothing ever changes on the screen, even after 15-20 minutes. The only thing I can do is hold the power button to turn it off.

The [Hardware Support Page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z#Installation_gotcha.27s) says that I should change a setting so that `acpi=off`, but I have no idea how to do that since the menu I see doesn't look like the one on the [Boot Options page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions).

Given that it appears to hang when the video resolution changes, might this have something to do with video card support? Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I actually just worked it out. If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while in the menu, then it shows a command line prompt which has a command prefilled in it, *similar* to this:

[image: ...initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --]

You can enter the options after the `--`, and in my case `... -- acpi=off` worked.

After installation, to make this a default for your grub menu, edit `/etc/default/grub` and set this option:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="-- acpi=off"
```

and then, run:

```
$ update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same notebook as you.
Once time i try to install an OS with a bootable USB drive and it not works. It only works when i burn a cd, i believe that's happend because of the USB 3.0.

Comment: If you plug your USB into the e-sata port, then it works.

Comment: See here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z#Installation_gotcha.27s